# Can all bits 0 be a trap representation for integers?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, calloc

It is common to assume that initializing an object to all bits 0 is a simple way to set all its members to `0`.  The standard does not guarantee this for non integer types as:

- all bits zero might not be a valid representation for pointers, even null pointers, although all common modern systems use exactly that.
- all bits zero might not be a legal representation for floating point numbers, although it is on IEEE compliant systems.

What about integers? Is the following code fully defined:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int *p = calloc(sizeof(*p), 1);
    if (p) {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        memset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you looking for a generic way to initialise any piece of memory to some sort of "safe" value?

Comment: I don't get this question... you are aware that calloc is the same thing as malloc+memset zero? Why the extra memset?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [C Standard, 6.2.6.2, Integer Types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p5)

> For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of a trap representation is, C11 6.2.6.1/5:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
>   value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>   not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced
>   by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
>   does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called
>   a trap representation.

This means that a trap representation has to be something that is not a valid value.

In case of two's complement, all binary combinations of an `int` are valid values, so trap representations aren't possible.

In case of wildly fictional one's complement systems, it would be possible to make the value `0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming 32 bit int) a trap representation, if negative zeroes are not supported. Similarly, on a wildly fictional signed magnitude system, the value `0x80000000` could be used as a trap representation.

On even wilder fictional systems, integers may have padding bits and then such padding bits could be used to hold trap representations.

In any of these cases, the binary representation 0 is always a value. A lot of the C standard depends on this, such as initialization of objects with static storage duration, the calloc() function, the values of padding bytes in structs etc etc. In all of these, the outcome shall not be a trap representation.

Please note that if you aren't a programmer of wildly fictional systems, none of this is of any concern. There may have existed a few odd, experimental computers where this was a thing. You may even find someone yet alive who can tell you about them.

If you are designing for compatibility with such exotic, most likely fictional systems, you should document in detail exactly why this compatibility is needed for your product. Since your boss probably wants to know why you are spending lots of time designing for compatibility with computers that actually don't exist in the real world.

Comment: Prior to C89, it would have been allowable for a system to use a representation that would trap if integers didn't have certain padding bits set, even if the value of all data bits was zero.  On such a system, static initialization would have been required to initialize integers to a valid zero value, but that's not a particularly exotic requirement, since even under C99 default initialization of pointers and floating-point values may require a bit pattern other than all bits zero.